# Ubuntu Studio 18.04 suddenly not charging battery on HP Elitebook 8460p

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, battery, ubuntu-studio

When the battery is installed, Xfce Power Manager will not recognize the power being plugged in, and so discharges the battery. When the battery is removed, the laptop operates perfectly fine on line power.

I've tried buying a new battery; the issue remains. The charger seems fine when tested with a voltmeter, and, as mentioned, the computer runs perfectly well when plugged in without a battery installed.

Running:

```
xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon --debug
```

...with the battery installed and the plug in gets me:

```
~$ xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon --debug

** (xfce4-power-manager:22185): WARNING **: 18:22:45.051: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.PowerManagement': no such name


** (xfce4-power-manager:22185): WARNING **: 18:22:45.052: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.xfce.PowerManager': no such name

TRACE[xfpm-main.c:205] xfpm_start(): Starting the power manager
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:642] xfpm_xfconf_init(): lock screen TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for general-notification
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-brightness-popup
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for handle-brightness-keys
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for hibernate-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for sleep-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-slider-min-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-sleep-mode
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for network-manager-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-power-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-suspend-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-hibernate-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for heartbeat-command
TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:75] xfpm_dpms_set_timeouts(): Settings dpms: standby=1200 suspend=0 off=3600


(xfce4-power-manager:22185): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:22:45.075: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'Changed' is invalid for instance '0x55f4faee8a20' of type 'GDBusProxy'
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:287] xfpm_polkit_init_data(): Using unix session polkit subject
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.power-off', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.reboot', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=FALSE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:936] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:898] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'line-power' device added
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:936] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:898] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'battery' device added
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:908] xfpm_power_add_device(): Battery device type 'battery' detected at: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.109: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.109: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.109: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:600:17: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.112: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.112: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.112: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:787:17: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.114: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.114: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.114: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1099:17: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.120: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2286:8: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.120: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2286:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.120: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2291:8: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.120: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2291:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4357:14: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4357:14: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4419:12: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4419:12: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4428:16: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4428:16: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4443:22: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.126: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4443:22: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.127: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4499:12: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.127: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4501:16: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.127: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4501:16: Expected a string.

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.127: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4549:12: not a number

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:22:45.127: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4549:12: Expected a string.
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 124 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_POWER_OFF)

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:22:45.150: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode

TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 213 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_HIBERNATE)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 150 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_SLEEP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 233 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 232 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 244 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 238 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 237 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:75] xfpm_dpms_set_timeouts(): Settings dpms: standby=900 suspend=0 off=1800

TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:348] xfpm_dpms_set_on_battery(): dpms on battery TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:213] xfpm_power_check_polkit_auth(): using logind suspend backend
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 22185>, 'start-time': <uint64 188564>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=FALSE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:645] xfpm_manager_inhibit_sleep_systemd(): Inhibiting systemd sleep: handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:22:45.167: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed

** (xfce4-power-manager:22185): WARNING **: 18:22:45.167: No outputs have backlight property
xfce4-power-manager-Message: 18:22:45.204: Set kernel brightness switch to 0
TRACE[xfpm-backlight.c:256] xfpm_backlight_brightness_on_ac_settings_changed(): Alarm on ac timeout changed 9
TRACE[xfpm-backlight.c:277] xfpm_backlight_brightness_on_battery_settings_changed(): Alarm on battery timeout changed 120

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:22:45.208: Failed to get keyboard max brightness level : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight' on object at path /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight

** (xfce4-power-manager:22185): WARNING **: 18:22:45.237: No outputs have backlight property

(xfce4-power-manager:22185): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:22:45.242: ../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:815: invalid property id 2 for "show-panel-label" of type 'GParamInt' in 'PowerManagerButton'
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:749] xfpm_manager_show_tray_icon(): Showing tray icon
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:539] power_manager_button_add_device(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:445] power_manager_button_update_device_icon_and_details(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
TRACE[xfpm-power-common.c:190] get_device_icon_name(): icon_suffix -symbolic, icon_base_length 12, upower_icon battery-full-symbolic
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:539] power_manager_button_add_device(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:445] power_manager_button_update_device_icon_and_details(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
TRACE[xfpm-power-common.c:190] get_device_icon_name(): icon_suffix -symbolic, icon_base_length 10, upower_icon ac-adapter-symbolic
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:539] power_manager_button_add_device(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
TRACE[../panel-plugins/power-manager-plugin/power-manager-button.c:445] power_manager_button_update_device_icon_and_details(): entering for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
TRACE[xfpm-power-common.c:190] get_device_icon_name(): icon_suffix -symbolic, icon_base_length 12, upower_icon battery-full-symbolic
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:723] xfpm_manager_tray_update_icon(): updating icon
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:707] xfpm_manager_tray_update_tooltip(): updating tooltip
```

I've looked around the BIOS for power management menus, but can't find any.

(edit to add) ALTHOUGH... I see now that Xfce Power Manager, with the battery taken out, still reads **Line Power: Not Plugged In, Device: line_power_AC, Type: Line power, PowerSupply True**... so I guess Xfce just isn't recognizing the line power at all. (end edit)

Any ideas would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release (see https://ubuntustudio.org/2018/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-released/).  It was a standard release with 9 months of supported life (the base had 5 years yes, but not the Studio components).  You could extended that by adding PPA (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/) but note Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not a long-term-support release.

Comment: I'd honestly forgotten that - it's been running fine for more than a year for me. Following your first link, it looks like 20.04 is LTS, so I could try upgrading to that and seeing if it makes this error clear up....

Comment: Your OS is only an observer when devices charge batteries (there are sure to be exceptions to this rule, but it applies to 99% of devices if not more). The charger is plugged in and device electronics recognize it & start changing the battery. The OS only recognizes this *event* and modifies it's panel, screen brightness or whatever other settings have been set, but does not take place in the actual charging (the electronics do that regardless of whether a OS is running, or device isn't even turned on). I suspect you have a hardware issue and changes to OS won't matter.

Comment: I didn't have time to read look/read your post before (when I posted my FYI link which was informational only) but my prior comment shows I don't think OS is involved, and it's not a Ubuntu/Ubuntu Studio issue, nor will release make any difference I believe.  The PPA provides updates for the Ubuntu Studio components of a 18.04 system (needed due to EOL status of U.Studio in 18.04), and should be reversed (ie. `ppa-purge` run) should you want to upgrade to 20.04. You can *release-upgrade* to 20.04, and if you're going to do that, I'd not bother with the PPA, PPA is if staying on 18.04.

Comment: I don't know your device, so my thinking may not apply, but I'd forget your installed system and see how it performs with something very different running from a *live* system (eg. OS running from thumb-drive). By something different, I'd likely choose a non-Ubuntu (probably non-Debian but Debian is as close as I'd go, nothing based on Ubuntu for sure & a very different software stack, ie. kernel etc).  Does it act the same on that *live* system... I suspect it may (which will be more interesting if you're using something different, a BSD for example, or if GNU/Linux opensuse or something)

Comment: I'm following your logic with the OS recognizing the *event*. 

I initially suspected a hardware issue, but am baffled by the power supply... powering... when there's no battery installed, and the fact that a new battery/power reset didn't change that. 

What would you suggest for a live thumb-drive OS? The only ones I have any experience on besides Ubuntu Studio are Ubuntu flavors (lubuntu and plain Ubuntu). 

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: All Ubuntu *flavors* have the same Ubuntu base, so much of the software stack will be identical. Very different maybe something like FuryBSD or one of the other spins of FreeBSD (that allow *live* use). BSDs have less hardware support so may not boot on every system. Less far away for the test, but more guaranteed to work would be a Fedora or OpenSuSE (not sure opensuse provides *live* systems by default, but they're available or you can use a spin like Gecko). If you're using a 4.15 (18.04 GA) kernel for example, I'd opt for a GNU/Linux running a different release of kernel ideally.

Comment: So I tried not a different OS per se, but d/led an HP diagnostic program that runs off a USB during startup, before the OS boots. While it was running, the same symptoms were evident, and the diagnostic itself says the problem is the power supply - so I'll go forward assuming the power supply is the problem (hopefully the plug and not the port).
Thanks for helping me reach this point!